# How to display a selected item on a list box coming from MS Access database to a text box?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to display the product id and price of a product from a listbox to its own textboxes called 'txtproductid' and 'txtprice' respectively.
Here's my code so far. No errors appeared and when executed. But nothing happens when i clicked my product on the listbox. It did not display its id and price. What could I be missing?

```
Public Class shop
    Dim provider As String
    Dim datafile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Private Sub listboxitems_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles listboxitems.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim lbconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\USER PC\Desktop\orderDB1.accdb")
    Dim lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE productid =' & listboxitems.Text & ' AND product ='" & listboxitems.Text & "' AND price =' & listboxitems.Text & '", lbconn)
    Dim lbreader As OleDbDataReader
    Try

    lbconn.Open()

    lbreader = lbcmd.ExecuteReader()
    While lbreader.Read
        txtproductid.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("productid")
        txtproduct.Text = lbreader.GetString("product")
        txtprice.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("price")


    End While

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    lbconn.Close()

End Sub
```

EDIT: Screenshot of my access database

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuQ7c.png)

[design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed314.png)

Comment: check the datatype in your excel sheet , and make sure that that is number in excel.

Comment: @sunilkarkala it's in Access, and yes its a number.Column "productid" is Number, "product" is Name, and "price" is Number

Comment: please see the querry  Dim lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE productid =' & listboxitems.Text & ' AND product ='" & listboxitems.Text & "' AND price =' & listboxitems.Text & '", lbconn) you didn't used double quotation mark for  listboxitems.Text  .

Comment: @sunilkarkala I got the error " The table 'productlog' is already opened exclusively by another user, or it is already open through the user interface and cannot be manipulated programmatically." I removed the double quotes from integer values because i read from another question that integers should use double quotes. It's really confusing.

Comment: @sunilkarkala I added an if statement that closes and opens the connection so the 'is already opened' error is fixed. but it still does not display the values even though I've already put double quotes. Is it okay to put a youtube video link here? just to show you what I'm trying to do?

Comment: i think you can post youtube link , please share the link , i will see to it.

Comment: @sunilkarkala https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7cCfCQ7E6Y  Here in the video, he's using SQL instead of MS Access. I just changed the mysql values to OleDB.

Comment: i did't find there is any problem with code can u send me the acess querry you are using to get the data from acess .

Comment: @sunilkarkala How can i send you the access query? Do i post a screenshot or send you the file? I apologize I'm quite new.

Comment: post the screen shot of the code

Comment: @sunilkarkala https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuQ7c.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed314.png

Comment: replace your querry with this querry ,

Comment: "SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE productid =" & listboxitems.Text & " AND product ='" & listboxitems.Text & "' AND price =" & listboxitems.Text & "

Comment: @sunilkarkala Still no luck. `Dim lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE productid =" & listboxitems.Text & " AND product ='" & listboxitems.Text & "' AND price =" & listboxitems.Text & "", lbconn)` like this? I copied your comment and added another quote after the last one cause an error appeared 'string constant must end with double quotes. but after adding nothing still appearing in the textboxes.

Comment: I am not able to understand where it is going wrong , can u check removing where condition ? , if it is something wrong with where condition.

Comment: @sunilkarkala I removed it. `Dim lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog", lbconn)` Still not showing.

Comment: or if is too important just send me code if possible , i can try it for u..

Comment: before u use lbreader.Read() please put if condition for checking the datareader has rows

Comment: if lbreader.hasrows() it will return true that means the reader has rows , i think the reader does not has any value to dispaly.

Comment: @sunilkarkala added the hasrows. `lbreader = lbcmd.ExecuteReader()
            If lbreader.HasRows() Then

                While lbreader.Read
                    txtproductid.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("productid")
                    txtproduct.Text = lbreader.GetString("product")
                    txtprice.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("price")


                End While
            End If`  Am i doing it right? It still doesn't show. How can i send  code?

Comment: yes please debug through that and check , if it not works please mail me at sunilkarkala90@gmail.com with db file

Comment: @sunilkarkala I also added a bit of `If lbreader.HasRows() Then
                MessageBox.Show("Has rows", "Project", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)` just to be sure and when i run it, it displayed the message.

Comment: with or without where condition? , there is problem with querry waht you are written ..based on which field you want to filter the data you are passing same value for productid ,product , price that is  listboxitems.Text  , if u are using same value for all fields , you will not get any result inreturn .

Comment: @sunilkarkala I modified the code to this `Dim lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM productlog WHERE product ='" & listboxitems.Text & "'", lbconn)` based on the youtube video i posted. He only got one on his command. It's the `name = '" & listbox.Text &"'` without the other fields but he managed to execute the code. If you look back at the video you'll find that its almost similar to my code. I just changed the connection and the OleDb functions yet I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @sunilkarkala I also attached the database to your email

Comment: @sunilkarkala Here's another link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbbZzaMZGhY  Its the same as this but the source code is not using database.

Comment: Exceptions exist to *tell you* what wrong - using an empty Catch just hides the error.  You are probably getting the same error as your last question.